# Bind texture with pinned mapped memory in CUDA

Tags: memory, cuda, textures

I was trying to bind a host memory that was mapped for zero-copy to a texture, but it looks like it isn't possible.

Here is a code sample:

```
float* a;
float* d_a;
cudaSetDeviceFlags(cudaDeviceMapHost);
cudaHostAlloc( (void **)&a, bytes, cudaHostAllocMapped);
cudaHostGetDevicePointer((void **)&d_a,  (void *)a, 0);

texture<float, 2, cudaReadModeElementType> tex;
cudaBindTexture2D( 0, &tex, d_a, &channelDesc, width, height, pitch);
```

Is it recommended that you used pinned memory and just copy it over to device memory that is bind to texture?

Comment: Is texture defined globally? also use cudaHostAllocWriteCombined if you are reading the texture from host memory

Comment: Yes, it is defined globally. cudaHostAllocWriteCombined just makes the read on the device side more efficient by avoiding cache.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, but you have to make sure the pitch is correctly aligned - at least 64B granularity.  I do not see an alignment requirement in cudaDeviceProp that you can use. cudaDeviceProp::textureAlignment will give you decent guidance - that is the alignment requirement for the base address of the texture, not the pitch; but I believe that alignment requirement is stricter than the pitch alignment requirement.

Unfortunately there is no cudaHostAllocPitch() to take care of this for you.

Fair warning: I have done quite a bit of directed performance testing of 1D texture-from-host-memory, and it is s-l-o-w.  Tesla class hardware goes at 2G/s and Fermi class hardware at 0.5 G/s.  I have no reason to believe 2D texturing will be any faster.